# How to create a 2-dimensional CellRendererToggle

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, gtk, gtk3

I want to create a table like this:

```
| |  username  | (x) task01 | (x) task02 |
|-|------------|------------|------------|
|x|  user0001  |    1.00    |    1.00    |
| |  user0002  |            |            |
etc...
```

A cell will be shown its value if its column and its row are being ticked.

I want to create a 2D CellRendererToggle which have tickboxes on the first row/column to choose a whole row/column.

I don't know how to code it in Python Gtk3.0. Help me!

Comment: Any code already? Where's the exact problem?

Comment: I coded an 1D CellRendererToggle, but I want to create a 2D one. I haven't coded the 2D yet.

Answer (score 0):

Your proposed solution isn't possible, but there's an easier way to do what you want: when you create the table column's attribute binding, simply bind the `visible` property of the other cell renderers to the same column in your model that the `active` property of the GtkCellRendererToggle is bound to. I don't know Python's GTK+ bindings, but it would look something like

```
# using 5, 6, and 7 as examples
column.add_attribute(toggleRenderer, "active",  5)
column.add_attribute(textRenderer1,  "text",    6)
column.add_attribute(textRenderer1,  "visible", 5)
column.add_attribute(textRenderer2,  "text",    7)
column.add_attribute(textRenderer2,  "visible", 5)
```